# SheepShaver failing to install application; Not Enough Memory

Tags: emulation, mac-os-classic, sheepshaver

I am trying to install "Kid Pix Deluxe 4" on Mac OS 9 using SheepShaver on Ubuntu 16.04.

A problem I am having is that when I try to install it, I get an error saying that I don't have enough memory. So I made a hard disk file with 4.8 GB on it and added it to SheepShaver, but when I try to select it when I am installing Kid Pix, it gives me the same error, saying 'Not enough room on OS9 to install'

I am using the OS9 image and the New World PPC ROM from Redundant Robot.

Comment: Hey Jordan, did you create a new account by mistake?  I've seen your other one [here](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/2148/jordan-m-baron).  You should mod flag for an account merger.

Comment: How much RAM is your virtual machine configured for?

Comment: I have it configured for 256MB of RAM

Comment: How much space is available on your hard drive and how much does Kid Pix Deluxe 4 need?

Comment: @JordanBaron I've found two duplicate accounts, with the help of the Mod tools. Are you [this account (with lots of activity)](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/2148/jordan-m-baron) and / or [this account (with very little to none, but on the same IP)](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/2188/jordan-baron)?

Answer (score 3):

The message “**Not enough room on OS9 to install**” suggests that it's not a memory problem, but an (emulated) disk space problem. The installation image you downloaded is labelled *OS9*, which is a clue.

Classic Mac OSs can be a bit precious about where they install software, so maybe Kid Pix is trying to install on a small installation image. Can you enlarge the image, or install on a much larger emulated disk?

Comment: For that matter, the disk might be too *large*, and the installer is seeing 2GB free as -1 bytes free.

Answer (score 2):

When it says, you've not enough memory, it is referring to RAM. For all of my virtual machines, I set the RAM to half of what is actually on my computer. I have a computer with 4GB of RAM. Even when I'm emulating Windows 3.1 and Tiny Core Linux, I use 2GB RAM for good measure. I suggest that if you use a computer for such, it should have at least 1GB of RAM.

Comment: aaa, do you have two accounts? Do you need them to be merged?

Comment: I think I might, but this is not a permanent account anyways. I'm not 14 yet so I'm unable to sign in via Yahoo! I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Ah it's listing you as unregistered. Are you under 13? You have to be 13 or older to register on the StackExchange network :(

Comment: I'm 13 but not 14 just yet. I do find my self fairly knowledgeable for my age.

Comment: So you probably can't register with Yahoo, but you could just create an account directly on StackExchange. If you do that we should be able to get your (so far) 2 accounts combined.

Comment: @aaa You're allowed to be a registered Stack Exchange user if you are 13 years old (which you are).

Comment: I use my email for everything. This December I'll be able to use my susestudio again. I'll join here, but thank you for your concern.

Comment: Too much memory can be a problem: if a program uses signed 32-bit arithmetic for its memory calculations, 2GB of RAM will show up as being -2 GB of RAM.

Comment: @aaa You *do* know that you can link more than one login to your account, right? And anyway, I think it would be a good idea to merge your accounts, so it's easier when you join in December to attribute your contributions to you. What do you think?

Comment: Alright, I guess that would be a good idea. How would I go about doing it

Comment: @aaa It's been done. A member of the Stack Exchange Community Moderation team has merged the two accounts.